# How do ASPX pages turn into System.Web.UI.Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET (`.aspx`) pages have a `<%@ Page %>` declaration at top that includes an `Inherits=""` attribute.  ASPX pages inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page` declarative-ly.

My question is, what code actually converts the `aspx` page into an object of type `System.Web.UI.Page` class?  Where in the lifecycle does this take place and what class is responsible for it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually occur during the page lifecycle.  By the time your Page object is invoked as a handler for a request, the .aspx has already been parsed and the code compiled into the underlying classes.

When this parsing and compilation occurs depends on the setup of your application.  If it's a "Web Site project", this compilation generally happens on the fly by the ASP.Net runtime, meaning that when it detects a request to a page that has not been requested before, or has been modified.

In pre-compiled websites, all the classes already exist and none of the runtime parsing and compilation happens.

The class that actually performs the conversion is a class called [PageParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageparser.aspx).  Essentially the ASP.Net runtime invokes this class' GetCompiledPageInstance method, which ends up compiling the page if it doesn't exist in memory already.

In terms of lifecycle - the Page lifecycle is nested in the [HttpApplication's "lifecycle"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx), which is in turn part of the http request processing pipeline.  It is well before the Page ever comes into the picture that this compilation happens.